# PyQt : Put several QTreeWidgetItem into columns of QTreeWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I made a function which allows to add item to a tree (parent + child or children).

```
def addItemsToSummary(self, parent, text, checkable=False, expanded=True):
    self.tabItems = []

    self.tabParent.append(text)

    self.item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [text])

    lhs, rhs = self.item.text(0).split("=", 1)
    self.nominalValue,_ = rhs.split(")", 1)
    print(self.nominalValue)
    self.val = re.findall('\w+', self.nominalValue)
    print(self.val)
    print(self.val[0])
    print(self.val[1])

    if checkable:
        self.item.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
    else:
        self.item.setFlags(self.item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    self.item.setExpanded(expanded)

    self.addChildToSummary(self.item, ["Nominal value = ", self.val[0], self.val[1]])
    self.addChildToSummary(self.item, ["Min =","",self.val[1]])
    self.addChildToSummary(self.item, ["Max =","",self.val[1]])
    self.addChildToSummary(self.item, ["Type = ", "float",''])
    self.addChildToSummary(self.item, ["Relation =","",""])

    if self.tabItems is not None:
        self.tabAnalysis.append(self.tabItems)

    return self.tabAnalysis, self.nominalValue
```

I made another function which allows to add each child to an item (parent).

```
 def addChildToSummary(self, parent, tab):
    item1 = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [tab[0]])
    item2 = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [tab[1]])
    item3 = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [tab[2]])
    item2.setFlags(item2.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
    self.tabChild.append((item1.text(0),item2.text(0),item3.text(0)))
    print(item2.text(0))
    self.tabItems.append([parent.text(0),(item1.text(0),item2.text(0),item3.text(0))])

    return item1, item2, self.tabItems
```

I would like to know if it is possible to put each `QTreeWidgetItem` into column of `QTreeWidget`.

Comment: Why not just have two columns of `QTreeWidgetItem`s which are children of whatever level you want, where the first column contains min/max labels that are not editable and the second column contains editable cells like the rest of your treeview?

Comment: That's a better idea, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def createGroup(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox()

        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()

        header=QTreeWidgetItem(["Tree","First","secondo"])
        #...
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderItem(header)   #Another alternative is setHeaderLabels(["Tree","First",...])

        root = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget, ["root"])
        A = QTreeWidgetItem(root, ["A"])
        barA = QTreeWidgetItem(A, ["bar", "i", "ii"])
        bazA = QTreeWidgetItem(A, ["baz", "a", "b"])

        barA.setFlags(barA.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        bazA.setFlags(bazA.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)

        # switch off "default" editing behaviour
        # as it does not allow to configure only an individual
        # column as editable
        self.treeWidget.setEditTriggers(self.treeWidget.NoEditTriggers)

        # to be able to decide on your own whether a particular item
        # can be edited, connect e.g. to itemDoubleClicked
        self.treeWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.checkEdit)


        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.treeWidget)

        vbox.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)

        return groupBox

    # in your connected slot, you can implement any edit-or-not-logic
    # you want
    def checkEdit(self, item, column):
    # e.g. to allow editing only of column 1:
        if column == 1:
            self.treeWidget.editItem(item, column)

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(300, 220)

        self.grid = QGridLayout()

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.createGroup(),1,0,1,2)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).